# Formatting a python number that is a string

Tags: python

I have a number in the form of (how to was parsed from a spreadsheet):

```
4.10045710008e+12 <type 'float'>
```

How would I convert this to an integer:

```
4100457100080
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f = 4.10045710008e+12
i = int(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also more simply

```
a=int(4.10045710008e+12)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if type(value) == float:
    value = int(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> f = 4.10045710008e+12

>>> type(f)

<type 'float'>

>>> int(f)

4100457100080L

>>>
```